# It's possible add more istructions to a conditional statement

Tags: c#, ternary-operator

Hi guys I have the following if

```
if(check)
{
    count++;
    push();
}
else 
{
   count--;
   pop();
}
```

I would like know if it's possible transform this if in a conditional statement

Something like this:

```
(check)?count++,push():count--,pop();
```

Comment: Yes, it's dosen't work

Comment: Though not possible, you can have `check ? count++ : count--;
check ? push() : pop();`

Comment: @PraveenJeganathan if ternary operator not return a value i have a compilation error: http://ideone.com/pjAU8M

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ternary operator requires a return value, so wrap your method in a delegate and return some dummy value(in this case `true`). You're done..

```
int count = 0;
Func<bool> func1 = () =>
{
    count++;
    push();
    return true;//To make compiler happy
};
Func<bool> func2 = () =>
{
    count++;
    push();
    return true;//To make compiler happy
};

var dummy = (check) ? func1() : func2();
```

Comment: Yup, this will work. But I see no reason to do this instead of the OPs original code ;)

Comment: @ØyvindKnobloch-Bråthen me too.. If at all you're curious about this kind of thing here is the way :)

Answer (score 3):

Ternary operator must **return** a value. So no, you can't change your conditional statement into ternary.

[?: Operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

Nope, you can't do that.

It is called a "ternal operator" (?:) and it can be only used for a value assignment like

```
var text = cond ? "yes" : "no";
```

Read more about it on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Although you can do

```
int PushMethod()
{
   push();
   return count + 1;
}

int PopMethod()
{
   pop();
   return count -1;
}
```

and use it like

```
count = cond ? PushMethod() : PopMethod();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define some `Count` property wrapping the `count` like this:

```
public int Count {
  get { return count;}
  set {
    int i = value - count;
    count = value;
    if(i == 1) push();
    else if(i == -1) pop();
  }
}
//then do it like this
Count += check ? 1 : -1;
```

Comment: It is much better than using a conditional statement itself =).

Comment: @Enam you may not understand the benefit of property, of course, the OP's requirement is some kind of **strange thing**. It can only be achieved in a neat way by the help of C# language developers.

Comment: OK, I didn't took that so serious.